# Cubic of a Gauss sum

Tags: number-theory, analytic-number-theory

> Let $p$ be an odd prime, $\chi$ a Dirichlet character of order 3 over
>   $\mathbb{F}_p-\{0\}$ and $\rho$ the quadratic character modulo $p$.
>
> Show that $g(\chi)^3=p\chi(2)J(\chi,\rho)$, where $g$ is the Gauss Sum
>   and $J$ is the Jacobi Sum.

I've already proved that $g(\chi)^2=\bar\chi(4)J(\chi,\rho)g(\chi^2)$ and I tried the following:

$g(\chi)^3=\bar\chi(4)J(\chi,\rho)g(\chi^2)g(\chi)=\bar\chi(4)J(\chi,\rho)g(\chi^{-1})g(\chi)$

but I don't know what to do next, cause if I substitute $g(\chi^{-1})g(\chi)$ by $J(\chi^{-1},\chi)g(\chi^{-1}\chi)$ then everything goes to cero because $g(\chi^{-1}\chi)=g(\epsilon)=0$.

Any suggestion?

Comment: something like $g(\chi^2) = g(\overline{\chi}) = \overline{g(\chi) }\chi(-1)$. And $g(|\chi|) = \sum_{n=1}^{p-1} e^{2i\pi n/p} = -1$ not $0$